# Calling ASMX Web Service and Binding to Telerik RadGrid via JavaScript won't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, telerik, telerik-grid

We are have an ASMX Web Service that has the attribute:

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class ReportDataService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

The Web Service returns JSON. We are trying to bind that Web Service that returns a JSON representation of a DataSet using JavaScript since we can't do it during Form Load. I don't know if the issue is calling via JavaScript or the RadGrid. Here is the JavaScript:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">   
function DoUpdate2(sbiId) {
            var input = '{"SbiId":"' + sbiId + '"}';
            var dataSource;

            {AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Services.ReportDataService.GetDataSetJSON(updateGrid);}
        }

        function updateGrid(result) {
            var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
            var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
            mtv.set_dataSource(result);
            mtv.dataBind();

        }
  </script></telerik:RadCodeBlock></head>
<body class="BODY">
  <form runat="server" id="mainForm" method="post" style="width: 100%;">
  <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager" runat="server">
    <Services>

      <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/ReportDataService.asmx" InlineScript="true"  />
    </Services>
       <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
               <%-- <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.smartmenus.min.js"/>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min.js"/>--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
               <%-- <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
             <%--   <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />    
                <%--Site Scripts--%>

            </Scripts>
  </telerik:RadScriptManager>
  <!-- content start -->
  <h3>
    RadGrid bound to live data:</h3>
      <p>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="DoUpdate2(1); return false" />
      </p>
      <div id="div"></div>
  <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <MasterTableView TableLayout="Auto">
      <Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProducerID" UniqueName="ProducerID" HeaderText="ProducerID">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContactID" UniqueName="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Contact" UniqueName="Contact" HeaderText="Contact">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Phone" UniqueName="Phone" HeaderText="Phone">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Fax" UniqueName="Fax" HeaderText="Fax">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PositionID" UniqueName="PositionID" HeaderText="PositionID">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AgencyContact" UniqueName="AgencyContact" HeaderText="AgencyContact">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
  </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
              <ClientSettings>
                     <ClientEvents OnCommand="function(){}"  />
               </ClientSettings>

</telerik:RadGrid>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```